# Identify this movie about bugs in space

Tags: identify-this-movie

I remember this movie about a group of people in a spaceship attacked by a bug colony. Finally, they crash land in an alien planet with weird plantation. There's also a weird aurora. The bug looks like robotic (I'm not sure).

This movie probably before 2000's. English language. In color.

Comment: Can you remember anything about the ship? the actors in it? I think i know what it is but i get told off if i give an answer to a question that looks likely to be closed :(

Comment: The robotic bugs is the main thing I remember.  :(

Comment: Were there any children present?

Comment: Rather than "plantation", try [Flora](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/flora)...

Comment: @JPhi1618 or vegetation

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## [Lost In Space](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=12&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjCvv3y98bTAhXsKMAKHXfeCQoQFghZMAs&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.imdb.com%2Ftitle%2Ftt0120738%2Fsynopsis&usg=AFQjCNGnJyW9oPZ2RzplIJ-e5yN0Jp0e3A&sig2=pdyzTJyslbFXoGcvZMFINg) - 1998

Starring Matt LeBlanc, William Hurt, Heather Graham and Gary Oldman. It is about a group of people, most of them from a family called the Robinsons, on a spaceship, the Jupiter 2. They are trying to get to the planet Alpha Prime as Earth is expected to be uninhabitable within 20 years.

[image: Jupiter2]

At one point they find another earth ship from the future *The Proteus*

[image: TheProteus]

This has an area full of plants and a strange creature.

[image: Plants]

[image: Creature]

Soon they are attacked by robotic spiders that had attacked the Proteus.

[image: Spiders]

[image: Spider]

They blow up the Proteus to kill the spiders and escape, however the explosion of the Proteus causes them to crash land on an alien planet below.

Where they find a time bubble and two of the crew from the future, Will (the son) and Dr Smith.

A fight ensues with the future Dr Smith, who has been turned into one of the spiders following a scratch. Smith is killed and the planet begins to break up creating a black hole, the Jupiter 2 manages to escape trying to complete its mission.

Comment: Yeah... that's the plantation and robotic bugs. Thank you so much

Comment: Swiss Family Robinson in space?

Comment: @MissMonicaE exactly that yes

Comment: I remember as a kid when that movie came out, it looked really interesting.  Reading this summary, I'm glad I never saw it.

Comment: @Wildcard it isn't a great film

Comment: I was under the impression that they *built* the time bubble.

Comment: @Amy the future versions built the time machine that caused the bubbles that they found

Comment: Oh, the bubbles were generated by the machine and extended into the past.  Then (?) their past-selves found the bubbles.  I see.

Comment: Sounds like they managed to capture the extreme schlock of the original 1960s series. A truly “worthy” successor. Let us hope no one ever tries again.

Answer (score 5):

I'm thinking that **Cearon** nailed it, but it's also possible that you are referring to [Starship Troopers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120201/?ref_=nv_sr_1), which came out in 1997.

The movie is about an alien species that has taken over a planet and that has attacked earth. Earth responds by sending out troops to attack the bugs. There are several scenes in space, where bugs are essentially shooting at the human's ships. Several ships get shot down.
[image]

At one point the bugs take over a human outpost:
[image]

Comment: This was my first thought too, but some of it doesn't line up with the question.  They weren't just a "group of people" and the planet is better described as a desert instead of having weird plants/plantations.

Comment: It's not the one. But, thank you for your answer. It's a nice movie.

Comment: Where's the plantation?  upvote anyway because courage, honor, duty

Comment: Remember, service guarantees citizenship!